# Custom post type archive false is not compatible with breadcrumbs

Tags: custom-post-types, breadcrumb

I have a custom post type (services) and archive page is as false (has_archive => false), when I visit single service post the breadcrumb contains url Services as url single (ID).

I change has_archive to true then it all works correctly and Service is created as a link and spaced accordingly, but i want to use has archive as false. I want create a page as services and use elementor plugin for custom it.

Do you have any solution?

Thank you

// Settings
    $separator          = '>';
    $breadcrums_id      = 'breadcrumbs';
    $breadcrums_class   = 'breadcrumbs';
    $home_title         = 'Inicio';

```
// If you have any custom post types with custom taxonomies, put the taxonomy name below (e.g. product_cat)
$custom_taxonomy    = 'product_cat';

// Get the query & post information
global $post,$wp_query;

// Do not display on the homepage
if ( !is_front_page() ) {

    // Build the breadcrums
    echo '<span id="breadcrums-custom' . $breadcrums_id . '" class="' . $breadcrums_class . '">';

    // Home page
    echo '<span class="item-home"><a class="bread-link bread-home" href="' . get_home_url() . '" title="' . $home_title . '">' . $home_title . '</a></span>';
    echo '<span class="separator separator-home"> ' . $separator . ' </span>';

    if ( is_archive() && !is_tax() && !is_category() && !is_tag() ) {

        echo '<span class="item-current item-archive"><strong class="bread-current bread-archive">' . post_type_archive_title($prefix, false) . '</strong></span>';

    } else if ( is_archive() && is_tax() && !is_category() && !is_tag() ) {

        // If post is a custom post type
        $post_type = get_post_type();



        // If it is a custom post type display name and link

        if($post_type != 'post') {

            $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
            $post_type_archive = get_post_type_archive_link('$post_type');

            echo '<span class="item-cat item-custom-post-type-' . $post_type . '"><a class="bread-cat bread-custom-post-type-' . $post_type . '" href="' . $post_type_archive . '" title="' . $post_type_object->labels->name . '">' . $post_type_object->labels->name . '</a></span>';
            echo '<span class="separator"> ' . $separator . ' </span>';

        }

        $custom_tax_name = get_queried_object()->name;
        echo '<span class="item-current item-archive"><strong class="bread-current bread-archive">' . $custom_tax_name . '</strong></span>';



    } else if ( is_single() ) {

        // If post is a custom post type
        $post_type = get_post_type();

        // If it is a custom post type display name and link
        if($post_type != 'post') {

            $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
            $post_type_archive = get_post_type_archive_link($post_type);

            echo '<span class="item-cat item-custom-post-type-' . $post_type . '"><a class="bread-cat bread-custom-post-type-' . $post_type . '" href="' . $post_type_archive . '" title="' . $post_type_object->labels->name . '">' . $post_type_object->labels->name . '</a></span>';
            echo '<span class="separator"> ' . $separator . ' </span>';


            // Standard page
        if( $post->post_parent ){

            // If child page, get parents 
            $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );

            // Get parents in the right order
            $anc = array_reverse($anc);

            // Parent page loop
            if ( !isset( $parents ) ) $parents = null;
            foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
                $parents .= '<span class="item-parent item-parent-' . $ancestor . '"><a class="bread-parent bread-parent-' . $ancestor . '" href="' . get_permalink($ancestor) . '" title="' . get_the_title($ancestor) . '">' . get_the_title($ancestor) . '</a></span>';
                $parents .= '<span class="separator separator-' . $ancestor . '"> ' . $separator . ' </span>';
            }

            // Display parent pages
            echo $parents;



        } 

        }
```

Comment: My breadcrums is f($post_type != 'post') {
                  
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
$post_type_archive = get_post_type_archive_link($post_type);
              
echo '<span class="item-cat item-custom-post-type-' . $post_type . '"><a class="bread-cat bread-custom-post-type-' . $post_type . '" href="' . $post_type_archive . '" title="' . $post_type_object->labels->name . '">' . $post_type_object->labels->name . '</a></span>';
                echo '<span class="separator"> ' . $separator . ' </span>';
              
            }

Comment: can you edit your question to include that code? WP doesn't provide breadcrumbs out of the box

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to register your custom post type? There are some typos throughout your question and your code, so it could be as simple as finding and fixing a typo. Or, you can try: unregister_post_type, then re-register your post type with has_archive false as you want your end result to be. It could be the changes you were trying to make didn't stick because the post type wasn't unregistered.